# Right approach to slice data

Tags: linux, awk, grep

i have a file (dataFile.txt) with missing data and all column with missing data are coded as -9

```
cat dataFile.txt
col1 col2 col3 col4
3 -9 2 4
2 4 6 -9
-9 3 1 2
```

I am using these two commands to get the lines with -9 i.e. the missing values

```
grep -e "-9" dataFile.txt |wc -l

awk '{if($0 ~ "-9") print}' dataFile.txt |wc -l
```

Am i doing right? (I am curious as after filtering missing values i am left with very few lines

Filtering commands

```
awk '{if($0 !~ "-9") print}' dataFile.txt |wc -l

grep -v -e "-9" dataFile.txt |wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the count of the lines which are having `-9` in them then these following solutions could help you on same.

***Solution 1st:***

```
awk '/-9/{count++} END{print count}'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:***

```
grep -c '\-9'  Input_file
```

Comment: @star, you did nothing wrong your both of the commands giving me 3 as output, cheers :)

Comment: Thank you so much have a blessed day

Comment: today i was just thinking as if these scripts count number of occurence of -9 or the number of lines that have -9. sorry if the post is closed